# Why does eslint-import-resolver-typescript not work correctly in my turborepo setup

Tags: eslint, turborepo, eslint-plugin-import

I am using a turborepo setup for my frontend nextJS applications and have this folder structure:

```
|--apps
|----template1
|------.eslintrc.js
|------package.json
|------tsconfig.json
|----template2
|------.eslintrc.js
|------package.json
|------tsconfig.json
|--packages
|----config-eslint
|------index.js
|------package.json
|----config-tsconfig
|------package.json
|------tsconfig.base.json
|------tsconfig.nextjs.json
|--.eslintrc.js
|--package.json
```

So far so good. As I was working in template1, everything worked fine and as expected. But now I started working in template2 and I have a weird behavior with my eslint plugins eslint-plugin-import and eslint-import-resolver-typescript, but only in either template1 or template2. It seems the plugins cannot manage both modules at the same time?? Is there something wrong with my config?

packages > config-eslint > package.json:

```
{
    "name": "eslint-config-base",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "update-dependencies": "npx npm-check-updates -u"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "8.44.0",
        "@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "^4.29.9",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.9",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
        "eslint-config-turbo": "^1.10.7",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "3.5.5",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
        "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0"
    }
}
```

packages > config-eslint > index.js:

```
/** @type {import("eslint").Linter.Config} */

module.exports = {
    root: true,
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', '@tanstack/query', 'import', 'unused-imports', 'prettier'],
    extends: [
        'plugin:import/recommended',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
        'plugin:@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query/recommended',
        'next',
        'turbo',
        'prettier',
    ],
    rules: {
        'import/order': [
            'error',
            {
                groups: ['builtin', 'external', 'internal', 'parent', 'sibling'],
                'newlines-between': 'always',
                alphabetize: {
                    order: 'asc',
                    caseInsensitive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        babelOptions: {
            presets: [require.resolve('next/babel')],
        },
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        project: ['tsconfig.json', 'packages/*/tsconfig.json'],
    },

    settings: {
        typescript: {},
        'import/parsers': {
            '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {
                alwaysTryTypes: true,
                project: ['./tsconfig.json', 'apps/*/tsconfig.json', 'packages/*/tsconfig.json'],
            },
        },
        react: {
            version: 'detect',
        },
    },
};
```

The package.jsons in template1 and template2 are equal besides external dependencies.
apps > template1/template2 > package.json:

```
{
    "name": "template2",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "next build",
        "dev": "open http://localhost:3202 && next dev --port 3202",
        "lint": "eslint --max-warnings 0 .",
        "lint-fix": "eslint --fix .",
        "tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
        "format-fix": "prettier --config ../../.prettierrc --write --ignore-unknown -l .",
        "update-dependencies": "npx npm-check-updates -u"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "config-tailwind": "*",
        "shared": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "config-tsconfig": "*"
    }
}
```

Now let me explain that weird behavior.
I have the exact same react component in my template1 and template2 module. In template1 there is no eslint error shown in vsCode and when I yarn lint the project, there are also no errors shown...so far so good.

In template2, the exact same component shows eslint import errors and when I auto-fix them, it reorders the imports and the errors are gone but it's not sorted the way I set the import/order rule. when I yarn lint the template2 project, I then get bunch of import errors which is expected, but the errors are not recognized by vsCode.

When I change the settings in my config-esling to only resolve the imports of one of these projects, it works. but both together dont work:

I was playing around with my eslint-configs but I only manage to get either template1 or template2 to recognize the import/order rules.

Only works for template1 (as expected):

```
settings: {
        typescript: {},
        'import/parsers': {
            '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {
                alwaysTryTypes: true,
                project: ['./tsconfig.json', 'apps/template1/tsconfig.json'],
            },
        },
        react: {
            version: 'detect',
        },
    },
```

Only works for template2 (as expected):

```
settings: {
        typescript: {},
        'import/parsers': {
            '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {
                alwaysTryTypes: true,
                project: ['./tsconfig.json', 'apps/template2/tsconfig.json'],
            },
        },
        react: {
            version: 'detect',
        },
    },
```

Only works for template1 (not as expected):

```
settings: {
        typescript: {},
        'import/parsers': {
            '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {
                alwaysTryTypes: true,
                 project: ['./tsconfig.json', 'apps/*/tsconfig.json', 'packages/*/tsconfig.json'],
            },
        },
        react: {
            version: 'detect',
        },
    },
```

Only works for template1 (not as expected):

```
settings: {
        typescript: {},
        'import/parsers': {
            '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {
                alwaysTryTypes: true,
                project: ['./tsconfig.json', 'apps/template1/tsconfig.json', 'apps/template2/tsconfig.json'],
            },
        },
        react: {
            version: 'detect',
        },
    },
```

Only works for template2: (just a different order of my project array... also not as expected)

```
settings: {
        typescript: {},
        'import/parsers': {
            '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {
                alwaysTryTypes: true,
                project: ['./tsconfig.json', 'apps/template2/tsconfig.json', 'apps/template1/tsconfig.json'],
            },
        },
        react: {
            version: 'detect',
        },
    },
```

I also tried to override the settings in the .eslint files of template1 and template2 itself, but that doesnt work either.

apps > template1 > .eslintrc.js:

```
/** @type {import("eslint").Linter.Config} */

module.exports = {
    root: true,

    parserOptions: {
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
    },

    extends: ['eslint-config-base'],
}
```

What am I doing wrong? For now I just disabled my import/order rule...
Any help appreciated!